# Invoke drawloop to attach some PDF to salesforce case object using apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I was trying to implement drawloop configuration by which I can attach pdf file to case object using webserive call. below is my code snippet.

The problem I am facing is that to get Session id of other users. If I logged in with requested user and execute following code it will work fine.

If I logged in with others users and executed following code it won't work then.won't attach pdf to case from drawloop.

Please if any one face the same issue. any help is highly appreciated.

```
@Future(callout=true)
public static void invokeDDP(Id caseID) {

       HTTP auth = new HTTP();
       HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
       req.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
       req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth');
       req.setMethod('POST');
       req.setBody('grant_type=password' +
              '&client_id= xxxx' + 
              '&client_secret= xxxx' +
              '&username= xxxx' +
              '&password= xxxx');

       HTTPResponse authresp=new HttpResponse();
       authresp = auth.send(req); 

       system.debug('response ->'+authresp);
       System.debug('BODY: '+authresp.getBody());
       System.debug('STATUS:'+authresp.getStatus());
       System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+authresp.getStatusCode());
       System.debug('\n response List -> '+authresp.getBody());
       Map<string, object > results =( Map<string, object >)Json.deserializeuntyped(authresp.getBody());
       String actoken =  (string)results.get('access_token');

       Loop__DDP__c ddps = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Loop__Custom_Integration_Options__r WHERE Name = 'Attach' LIMIT 1) FROM Loop__DDP__c WHERE Name ='Attach' LIMIT 1];

       Loop.loopMessage lm = new Loop.loopMessage();
       lm.sessionId = actoken;
       lm.batchNotification = Loop.loopMessage.Notification.ON_ERROR;

       lm.requests.add(new Loop.loopMessage.loopMessageRequest(
              caseID,
              ddps.Id,
              new Map < string, string > {
                     'deploy' => ddps.Loop__Custom_Integration_Options__r[0].Id
              }
       ));

       lm.sendAllRequests();
}
```